# TicTacToe game. Not working properly

Tags: java

folks, I've finished the code on the game of TicTacToe from scratch and it works fine if any of the players get same values in one line either horizontally or vertically or diagonally. But if the game is tie such as the follwing:

```
X O X 
O X X 
O X O 

Player #2 (O) enter the row and column numbers:
```

the code will still be asking for the user input despite the fact that I've set a limit in `count`. User has to input in total of `9` input characters as there are `9` boxes in TicTacToe. Everytime a user enters a `row` and `col` numbers the `count` increments by `1`. My `while-loop` looks like this:

```
while(!(count > 9)){
.....................
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my `while` loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
public class TicTacToe {

    public static final char[][] theBoard = new char[4][4];
    static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){


        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to TicTacToe!");
        System.out.println("Player #1 is X! \nPlayer #2 is Y!");
        System.out.println();
        getBoard();
        System.out.println();
        playGame();
    }

    public static void getBoard(){
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < theBoard[i].length; j++){
                theBoard[i][j] = '_';
                System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void playGame(){
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        boolean check = false;
        int count = 0;

        while(!(count > 9)){

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Player #1 (X) enter the row and column numbers: ");
            row = kbd.nextInt();
            col = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            count++;
            if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > theBoard.length
                    || col > theBoard.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The numbers should be in range 1-3");
            }

            else if (theBoard[row][col] != '_') {
                throw new RuntimeException("The space already filled!");
            }

            else {
                theBoard[row][col] = 'X';
                for (int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < theBoard.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            check = checkIfWin();
            if(check == true){
                break;
            }


            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Player #2 (O) enter the row and column numbers: ");
            row = kbd.nextInt();
            col = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            count++;

            if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > theBoard.length
                    || col > theBoard.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The numbers should be in range 1-3");
            }

            else if (theBoard[row][col] != '_') {
                throw new RuntimeException("The space already filled!");
            }

            else {
                theBoard[row][col] = 'O';
                for (int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < theBoard.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            check = checkIfWin();
            if(check == true){
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The game is tie!");
    }

    private static boolean checkIfWin(){
        boolean result = false;
        int countX = 0;
        int countO = 0;

        //Check 1st line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[1][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[1][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 2nd line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[2][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[2][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 3d line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[3][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[3][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 1s column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][1] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][1] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 2nd column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][2] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][2] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 3d column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][3] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][3] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }

        //Check first diagonal
        if(theBoard[1][1] == 'X' && theBoard[2][2] == 'X' && theBoard[3][3] == 'X'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
        }
        else if(theBoard[1][1] == 'O' && theBoard[2][2] == 'O' && theBoard[3][3] == 'O'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
        }


        // Check first diagonal
        if (theBoard[1][3] == 'X' && theBoard[2][2] == 'X'&& theBoard[3][1] == 'X'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
        } else if (theBoard[1][3] == 'O' && theBoard[2][2] == 'O'&& theBoard[3][1] == 'O') {
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Print out the value of `count` at the top of your `while` loop to see whether it actually has the value you think it should have.

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to learn how to debug.  Do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue stems from that fact that you give every player the chance to go. You need to add another check in the middle of your loop. In Tic Tac Toe, not every player gets equal turns, so you did you check after everyone went, rather than when the game could be complete.

You need another check here (in my code it was line 67):

```
            check = checkIfWin();
            if((check == true) || (count >= 8)){
                break;
            }
```

This program works:

```
package tictactoe;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe {

    public static final char[][] theBoard = new char[4][4];
    static Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){


        System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to TicTacToe!");
        System.out.println("Player #1 is X! \nPlayer #2 is Y!");
        System.out.println();
        getBoard();
        System.out.println();
        playGame();

    }

    public static void getBoard(){
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < theBoard[i].length; j++){
                theBoard[i][j] = '_';
                System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static void playGame(){
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        boolean check = false;
        int count = 0;

        //change this 
        while(count <= 8){
            count++;
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Player #1 (X) enter the row and column numbers: ");
            row = kbd.nextInt();
            col = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.println();


            if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > theBoard.length
                    || col > theBoard.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The numbers should be in range 1-3");
            }

            else if (theBoard[row][col] != '_') {
                throw new RuntimeException("The space already filled!");
            }

            else {
                theBoard[row][col] = 'X';
                for (int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < theBoard.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            check = checkIfWin();
            //change this
            if((check == true) || (count >= 8)){
                break;
            }


            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Player #2 (O) enter the row and column numbers: ");
            row = kbd.nextInt();
            col = kbd.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            count++;

            if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row > theBoard.length
                    || col > theBoard.length) {
                throw new RuntimeException("The numbers should be in range 1-3");
            }

            else if (theBoard[row][col] != '_') {
                throw new RuntimeException("The space already filled!");
            }

            else {
                theBoard[row][col] = 'O';
                for (int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 1; j < theBoard.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(theBoard[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            check = checkIfWin();
            if(check == true){
                break;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("The game is tie!");
    }

    private static boolean checkIfWin(){
        boolean result = false;
        int countX = 0;
        int countO = 0;

        //Check 1st line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[1][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[1][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 2nd line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[2][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[2][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 3d line
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[3][i] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[3][i] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 1s column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][1] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][1] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 2nd column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][2] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][2] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }
        countX = 0;
        countO = 0;

        //Check 3d column
        for(int i = 1; i < theBoard.length; i++){
            if(theBoard[i][3] == 'X'){
                countX++;
            }
            else if(theBoard[i][3] == 'O'){
                countO++;
            }
            if(countX == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
                break;
            }
            else if(countO == 3){
                result = true;
                System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
                break;
            }
        }

        //Check first diagonal
        if(theBoard[1][1] == 'X' && theBoard[2][2] == 'X' && theBoard[3][3] == 'X'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
        }
        else if(theBoard[1][1] == 'O' && theBoard[2][2] == 'O' && theBoard[3][3] == 'O'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
        }


        // Check first diagonal
        if (theBoard[1][3] == 'X' && theBoard[2][2] == 'X'&& theBoard[3][1] == 'X'){
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #1 (X) Wins!");
        } else if (theBoard[1][3] == 'O' && theBoard[2][2] == 'O'&& theBoard[3][1] == 'O') {
            result = true;
            System.out.println("The Player #2 (O) Wins!");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

As a side note, I found this bug by using the debugger and stepping through the program.

Comment: Define "DOES NOT WORK". Because, that loop will prevent it from executing if the count is more than 9. If that doesn't fix it, then there is another issue.

Comment: It'll still be asking for the user input even if I've set the `while(count<=8)`. @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: After debugging your program, I've edited and fixed the problem. As I stated originally, there was another issue.

Comment: where exactly? I've been trying for a long time

Comment: See the comments in my code. You need another check after player 1 goes. I've updated the answer. Please review.